# Min3d not working with device camera

Tags: android, face-detection, min3d

I am doing research on Face detection.
I did this using Google Vision api.
Now I want to load 3D modal(.obj file) using min3D.
I was successful in loading 3D modal.

Problem:I am not able to load 3d objects from min3D when camera is being used in app.

Thanks.